# sorting of two lists into one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have two classes which contains properties & i have a class which contains a list of the two classes as its property. I am supposed to return back a single list which contains the objects of both the classes sorted on created_date.Can any1 help? I have pasted the 3 classes below:

This is the first class:-

```
public partial class TouchPointModel : BaseModel
{
    public List<EntityModel> Entities { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
    public int TouchPointId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_date{ get;set; }
}
```

This is the second class:-

```
public partial class SurveyModel : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SelectedEntityId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedEntityType { get; set; }
    public int ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public bool IsMyProjects { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_date{ get;set; }
}
```

& this is the common class

```
public partial class RecentInteractionsModel
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public List<TouchPointModel> TouchPoints { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyModel> Surveys { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityTypeId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedParentId { get; set; }
}
```

To the UI i am supposed to show the latest touchpoints or surveys depending on the created date.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Does `SurveyModel` also derive from `BaseModel`?

Comment: Yes survey model also derives from base model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like you are going to need an `Interface` between the two `Classes`

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   DateTime Created_date{ get;set; }

   // add any other common properties between the 2 models

}


public partial class TouchPointModel : BaseModel, IMyInterface
{
   .......

   public DateTime Created_date{ get;set; }
}

public partial class SurveyModel : IMyInterface
{
   .......

   public DateTime Created_date{ get;set; }
}
```

Then you can create a single list `IMyInterface`

```
List<IMyInterface> allItems = TouchPoints.Cast<IMyInterface>()
                       .Union(Surveys.Cast<IMyInterface>())
                       .OrderBy(x => x.Created_date).ToList();
```

Comment: or if both derive from `BaseModel` you could use this variant on sa_ddam213 solution: replace `IMyInterface` with `BaseModel` as in:
  List<BaseModel> allItems = 
     TouchPoints.Cast<BaseModel>()
                .Union(Surveys.Cast<BaseModel>())
                .OrderBy(x => x.Created_date).ToList();

Comment: @JayWalker, I dont think `BaseModel` will be a good place to store these types of properties, as `BaseModel` is probably used in a lot more places that wont need them. But if it is just used on these 2 classes then yes that would work fine :)

Comment: It looked like both classes might already derive from `BaseModel` and that `Create_date` might be defined there. If so then using `BaseModel` with your Linq would be simple. Since we don't have the code for `BaseModel` I can't be sure.